# How to keep asking for user Input untill user chooses exit?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a "choice" menu, where I am using a switch/case function to make the user choose. The problem in my code is that I want it to keep asking for input until the user types in "sair" which means "exit" in portuguese. When they type "ajuda" which means "help" they get a list of available commands to execute, but if the user types "ajuda" then the "sout" is executed and build is finished, the program ends there...
My goal is to make it run until we choose to stop, I think there was a ways using readln or similar.

Anyways, here's the chunk of code regarding to the choice:

```
 public static String escolha() {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String strEscolha = userInput.next();
    boolean sair = false; 

    do {
        switch (strEscolha) {
            case "ajuda":
                System.out.println("Comandos disponiveis:");
                System.out.println("Ajuda; Fogo; Jogo; Resposta; Estado; Acaso; Reset; Sair;");
                break;

            case "Ajuda":
                System.out.println("Comandos disponiveis:");
                System.out.println("Ajuda; Fogo; Jogo; Resposta; Estado; Acaso; Reset; Sair;");
                break;

            case "sair":
                System.out.println("Obrigado por jogar!");
                sair = true;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Comando Invalido!");
                continue;

        }

    } while (sair == false);

    return null;

}
```

If anyone has a simple way to make it keep asking for commands, please let me know :(
Thanks in advance!!
PS: I just started, plese don't judge, my knowledge on java is neglectable :\

Comment: @AndyTurner still doesn't work :\ but thanks for the fast reply! :)

Comment: When do you think `return strEscolha;` is executed and what do you think it does?

Comment: Also you shouldn't create `new Scanner(System.in);` each time you invoke a method, but create it once and pass it to method which needs it.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, I put it static outside :)

Comment: Parallel to your problem, I would recommend changing the condition in the switch to `strEscolha.toLowerCase()`. In that way, you wouldn't need to have the same code for the option that starts with a capital. An alternative, in case you need the same handling code for two options in a switch would be to specify the two cases without breaking, like this: `case "ajuda": case "Ajuda": System.out.println("yay!"); break;` .

Comment: @deepdownunder2222 Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, that `continue` is not needed. The reason why we call break after (almost) every case is because, otherwise, all the code that follows (including the code in the following cases) in the switch will be executed until it either encounters a `break` or the switch ends. Good luck!

Comment: @deepdownunder2222 Thanks man, apreciate it! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your code is that you do not request user input in the 'ajuda' case.

Here is the code with some minor changes and some comments and recommendations:

```
    // if your method isn't supposed to return anything, simply make it void
public static void escolha() {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    // print some useful information when the application starts, so that the user knows
    // what to do
    System.out.println("Comandos disponiveis:");
    System.out
            .println("Ajuda; Fogo; Jogo; Resposta; Estado; Acaso; Reset; Sair;");
    String strEscolha = userInput.next();
    boolean sair = false; 

    do {
        // remove duplicate case by converting the input to lower letters
        switch (strEscolha.toLowerCase()) {
        case "ajuda":
            System.out.println("Comandos disponiveis:");
            System.out
                    .println("Ajuda; Fogo; Jogo; Resposta; Estado; Acaso; Reset; Sair;");
            // read the user input
            strEscolha = userInput.next();
            System.out.println(strEscolha);
            break;
        case "sair":
            System.out.println("Obrigado por jogar!");
            sair = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Comando Invalido!");
        }

    } while (sair == false);
    // do not forget to close the scanner, it might cause a memory leak
    userInput.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I had found a solution somewhat different, but your answer would solve it too!
What I did wrong was put the "String strEscolha = userInput.next();" **outside** of the loop, I had to put it inside the loop because otherwise the strEscolha would always be the same and the loop would never stop! :) doing what you said "userInput.close();" would also stop it from looping infinitely! :D

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove the `System.exit`, or you will shut down the entire JVM without executing the subsequent code (your IDE may have given you a dead code warning about this).

Secondly, you need to use `sair == false` (or, better, `!sair`) instead of `sair = false`. The former is a comparison; the latter is an assignment, making `sair` false.

`do { ... } while (false)` will execute the loop body once, but will not repeat.

Thirdly, the `return strEscolha;` immediately before `while` will cause the method to return before it attempts to loop, so it should be removed.

Comment: still doesn't work :\ but thanks for the fast reply! :)

Comment: `System.exit(0)` will shut the app down before even reaching that line.

Comment: @LuisAlmeida What do you mean "still doesn't work"? Have you tried debugging this in your debugger?

Comment: @jah that would mean it never loops in all cases, since `while (!sair)` would be false.

Comment: @LuisAlmeida please don't edit your question on the basis of these suggestions. The answer relates to the question asked; if you have subsequently changed it (without retaining the original question), the answer no longer makes sense, and is of no use to later readers; the question does not make sense either if the code has been edited to work.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I remove "sair" and make it "do {..} while (true)" it makes it repeat the "sout" infinitely :0

Comment: @LuisAlmeida OK, forgot you were in a switch. You can do it if you label the outer loop (e.g. `outer: do {`) and then use `break outer;` instead of `break`; however, I've just removed this from the answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for your help man, but it still doesn't loop, I really can't figure it out, can it be because of "return null" or something? Did everything you told me but it still ends after I type the "help" (ajuda" command :(